# Modeling quadratic function parameters as a function of variables

Tags: r, mixed-model, linear-model, bugs, quadratic-form

I'm modeling a response variable that varies seasonally.  The pattern is relatively well described by a quadratic function.  As the data have been collected over many (~50) years, I'm interested to know whether the parameters that describe the quadratic form change over time.  In particular, I'm interested in:

(1) Is the vertex of the quadratic function changing, and
(2) Is the width of the quadratic function changing (i.e., is the parabola becoming wider or narrower over time)?

I'm not interested in vertical shifts in the function over time, thus I also include a random intercept for year.

It's most intuitive to me, given my questions, to think about the vertex form of the quadratic function:

$$y = a(x - h)^2 + c$$

Here, $a$ controls the width of the parabola and $h$ controls the horizontal shift in the vertex.  I'd like to model $a$ and $h$ as a function of time (year). $c$ controls the vertical position of the parabola and thus I model it as a random effect of year.

We can simulate some data to make this more concrete and establish the change in parabola width ($a$ parameter) and vertex ($h$ parameter) as a function of time.

```
# Basic structure is 16 surveys over about 180 days (~half year), repeated yearly for 52 years
t = seq(-90, 90, length.out = 16) # 16 surveys over half a year; t ~ day of year
yr = seq(52) # 52 years of surveys

# Influence of yr on a and h
# a ~ -0.000005 / yr (becoming narrower)
# h ~ +0.5 / yr (vertex shifting later)

df <- expand.grid(t = t, yr = yr)
df$y <- with(df, (-0.000005 * yr - 0.00034) * (t - (0.5 * yr) + 20)^2 + rep(11, nrow(df)) + rnorm(nrow(df), 0, 0.5))
```

The plot shows the expected pattern: the vertex of the parabola is shifting right and the parabola is becoming increasingly narrow as time (year) progresses.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(jitter(t), y)) + geom_line(aes(group = yr, colour = yr)) + theme_bw()
```

[image: data plot]

Given the vertex form of the quadratic function, and that I wanted the $a$ and $h$ parameters to vary with time, a hierarchical model seemed the most intuitive.

So, I tried to write a WinBUGS model for it, with some success:

```
# This WinBUGS model was saved to a text file: test_bugs.txt
model{

    # Model
    for (i in 1:n_survs) {
        y[i] ~ dnorm(y.hat[i], tau.y)

        # EDIT: WinBUGS doesn't like "^"   
        # y.hat[i] <- a[i] * (t[i] - h[i])^2 + c[yr[i]]
        y.hat[i] <- a[i] * (t[i] - h[i]) * (t[i] - h[i]) + c[yr[i]]
        a[i] <- a.0 + a.year * yr[i]
        h[i] <- h.0 + h.year * yr[i]
    }

    # Priors
    a.0 ~ dnorm(0, 1.0E-6)
    a.year ~ dnorm(0, 1.0E-6)
    h.0 ~ dnorm(0, 1.0E-6)
    h.year ~ dnorm(0, 1.0E-6)
    tau.y <- 1/(sigma.y * sigma.y)
    sigma.y ~ dunif(0, 100)

    for (j in 1:n_yrs) {
        c[j] ~ dnorm(mu.c, tau.c)
    }

    mu.c ~ dnorm(0, 1.0E-6)
    tau.c <- 1/(sigma.c * sigma.c)
    sigma.c ~ dunif(0, 100)

}
```

The relevant call in R:

```
library(R2WinBUGS)
data <- list(n_survs = nrow(df), n_yrs = length(yr),
             y = df$y, t = df$t, yr = df$yr)

parameters <- c("a.0", "a.year", "h.0", "h.year",
                "sigma.y", "sigma.c")

inits <- function(){
    list(a.0 = rnorm(1), a.year = rnorm(1), h.0 = rnorm(1), h.year = rnorm(1),
         c = rnorm(52, 0, 0.25), sigma.y = runif(1), sigma.c = runif(1))
}

model <- bugs(data, inits, parameters, model.file = "test_bugs.txt",
              n.chains = 2, n.iter = 8000, n.burnin = 5000, n.thin = 1,
              bugs.directory = "your/path/to/WinBUGS14/",
              debug = TRUE, working.directory=getwd())
```

<strike>This results in a "Trap: incompatible copy" error in WinBUGS.  It never gets past `check(test_bugs.txt)` so I've probably written the model incorrect which is perhaps not surprising given it's my first attempt at a WinBUGS model.  I've looked at it for nearly two days now without any success, and the interwebs and WinBUGS documentation havn't sparked a solution.</strike>

**EDIT: With the code correctly specified, WinBUGS recovers the simulated parameters fairly well.  There appears to be some convergence issues for a few of the variables (see trace plots below) and I'm not sure why the effective sample size is 1 for `a.0` and `a.year`, but the density plots for those parameters seem reasonable.  Longer chains and thinning might help resolve this issue...**

```
model

Inference for Bugs model at "test_bugs.txt", fit using WinBUGS,
 2 chains, each with 8000 iterations (first 5000 discarded)
 n.sims = 6000 iterations saved
           mean  sd   2.5%    25%    50%    75%  97.5% Rhat n.eff
a.0         0.0 0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    1     1
a.year      0.0 0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    1     1
h.0       -20.9 0.9  -22.7  -21.5  -20.9  -20.4  -19.2    1   160
h.year      0.5 0.0    0.5    0.5    0.5    0.5    0.6    1   200
sigma.y     0.5 0.0    0.5    0.5    0.5    0.5    0.5    1  1900
sigma.c     0.0 0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.1    0.1    1  3600
deviance 1199.1 7.5 1183.0 1194.0 1200.0 1204.0 1212.0    1  6000

For each parameter, n.eff is a crude measure of effective sample size,
and Rhat is the potential scale reduction factor (at convergence, Rhat=1).

DIC info (using the rule, pD = Dbar-Dhat)
pD = 14.1 and DIC = 1213.1
DIC is an estimate of expected predictive error (lower deviance is better).
```

Coda plots

```
model_coda <- as.mcmc.list(model)
plot(model_coda) # Some figures snipped
```

[image: coda plots]

So, my questions:

(1) Does extracting the effects of `yr` on the $a$ and $h$ parameters of the quadratic function require a hierarchical solution similar to what I've attempted in WinBUGS above?

**EDIT: It doesn't strictly seem to require it (see below), but it seems the more intuitive specification.**

(2) If so, is there some glaring misspecification that I've missed?

**EDIT: Yes, WinBUGS doesn't seem to allow `x^2` but rather preferes `x * x`**

(3) Does a likelihood-based alternative exist?

**EDIT:  As @whuber suggested, a reparameterization of the quadratic function allows us to generate estimates for the $a$ and $h$ parameters in a likelihood-based mixed model framework.  How $a$ and $h$ change as with time is, I suppose, derived using interaction terms.  The code below generates reasonable point estimates for the `a.0` and `a.year` parameters, but I'm considerably less certain how to get point estimates for `h.0` and `h.year`.  Variation in these estimates seems most easily derived via bootstrapping (not illustrated; also see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21167/standard-error-of-a-ratio)):**

```
# Likelihood-based parameterization
df$t2 <- with(df, t * t)
library(lme4)
mod <- lmer(y ~ t2 + t2:yr + t + t:yr + (1|yr), data = df)  
coefs <- summary(mod)$coefficients
```

`a.0` is estimated by:

```
(a.0 <- coefs["t2", "Estimate"])
[1] -0.0003460573
```

`a.year` is estimated by:

```
(a.year <- coefs["t2:yr", "Estimate"])
[1] -5.07106e-06
```

`h.0` and `h.year` seem a bit removed from their expected values.

Might `h.0` be estimated by:

```
(-1/2) * (coefs["t", "Estimate"] + coefs["yr:t", "Estimate"]) / (a.0 + a.year)
[1] -23.08452
```

or

```
(-1/2) * coefs["t", "Estimate"] / a.0
[1] -24.02482
```

And `h.year` is possibly:

```
(-1/2) * (h.0 + coefs["yr:t", "Estimate"]) / a.0  
[1] 0.6020199
```

Thanks very much for the assistance.  My session information:

```
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] R2WinBUGS_2.1-21 boot_1.3-16      coda_0.17-1      ggplot2_1.0.1
```

Comment: Re (3), since $a(x-h)^2 + c$ can be rewritten $ax^2 + (-2ah)x + (ah^2 + c) = \beta_2x^2+\beta_1x+\beta_0$, you can test for changes in width by tracking the estimates $\hat\beta_2$ and for changes in location via the estimates $-(1/2)\hat\beta_1/\hat\beta_2$. The first is straightforward while the latter can be accomplished within a Maximum Likelihood estimation framework. BTW, my first reaction to an "incompatible copy" error would be to reinstall the software. Have you been able to load your model directly into WinBUGS (without using R)?

Comment: @whuber Thanks very much.  Turns out WinBUGS doesn't play nicely with "^" to indicate exponents, so I edited the WinBUGS model file and it runs without error.  I'm working on an edit that incorporates the WinBUG results and your suggested parameterization in a likelihood-based approach.